# This database cannot be imported error

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

I am trying to use LINQ to SQL to update my database however when I try to refresh my table after I have update it an error comes up saying:

> This database cannot be imported. It is either an unsupported SQL Server version or an unsupported database compatibility.

I'd appreciate any help from someone

Some random snippets from my code, not sure if they are relevant:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

-

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ProjectDBDataContext Context = new ProjectDBDataContext();
        var r =
                from b in Context.TeacherDetails
                where b.TeacherId <= 2
                select b;


           foreach (TeacherDetail b in r)            
              b.First_Name = "Jerry";

           Context.SubmitChanges();


    }
```

-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TeacherDetails] (
[TeacherId]     INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[First Name]    NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Surname]       NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Email Address] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Password]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Title]         NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
[Username]      NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_TeacherDetails] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([TeacherId] ASC)
);
```

Is this what you mean by connection strings?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

  <configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Project.Properties.Settings.ProjectDBConnectionString"
            connectionString="Data Source=   (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\ProjectDB.mdf;Integrated      Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you show us your connection string?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14877825/insert-statement-into-sql-server-database

Comment: This seems more like your answer: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ad837d14-31ea-445f-b830-1a8682b69e68/faq-my-database-isnt-being-updated-but-no-errors-occurred-in-my-application?forum=adodotnetdataproviders

Comment: Added my connection strings

Comment: Not to sounds annoying but I'm not really the best programmer and I'd prefer if someone helps me directly instead of having to replicate it from reading another website/ link as I don't really understand the link you provided. But I appreciate the help